# ExtractTopic Transformation in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My data is like below,

```
{"empid"="100","empname="test"}
```

Now, my transform is,

```
'transforms' ='IndexName',
'transforms.IndexName.type' = 'io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value',
'transforms.IndexName.field' = 'test',
'transforms.IndexName.skip.missing.or.null' = 'true'
```

I am creating the sink connector for elasticsearch. while using the above transform I can create the index name like "test". But I want to customize the index name like "test100". is it possible?

Comment: That payload is not valid JSON, and so those transforms will not work

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use more than one transform to modify `test` to `testblah`

[Add a `RegexRouter`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html) after the extraction to update the topic name with static content

```json
"transforms" = "IndexName,AddSuffix"
"transforms.IndexName.type" = ...
...
"transforms.AddSuffix.type" = ...
...
```

If you're trying to pull the `empid=100` field, there is no current transform that can extract & concatenate more than one field, and I would question your design choices for having one Elasticsearch index *per empid*